# BLOOM-GENERATE is not generating generating executable files

Tags: ros, deb, ros-kinetic, bloom-release, debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I've been trying to create deb files from my rospackages using bloom-generate command:

```
$ cd path/to/your/catkin/package
$ bloom-generate rosdebian --os-name ubuntu --ros-distro kinetic
$ fakeroot debian/rules binary
or
$ dpkg-buildpackage -b -uc
```

after this I normally install my package:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i my_ros_package.deb
```

If I do :

```
$ roscd my_ros_package
```

I obtain this:

```
opt/ros/kinetic/share/my_ros_package$
```

but when I try to execute:

```
$rosrun my_ros_package my_ros_package_node
  [rosrun] Couldn't find executable named my_ros_package_node  below/opt/ros/kinetic/share/my_ros_package
```

It works fine when I use catkin. I used a generic example because this is happening with all of my_packages.
But I will leave a concrete example here:

[Cmakelists](https://pastebin.com/ms7ewuDU)

[package.xml](https://pastebin.com/Y2xsH1fw)

---

Edit:

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(octo_to_pcl)

## Compile as C++11, supported in ROS Kinetic and newer
 add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  std_msgs
  map_msgs
  tf
  roslaunch
  geometry_msgs
  sensor_msgs
)
find_package (OpenCV)
find_package( PCL REQUIRED )
find_package(octomap REQUIRED)

## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
# find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)


## Uncomment this if the package has a setup.py. This macro ensures
## modules and global scripts declared therein get installed
## See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html
# catkin_python_setup()

################################################
## Declare ROS messages, services and actions ##
################################################

## To declare and build messages, services or actions from within this
## package, follow these steps:
## * Let MSG_DEP_SET be the set of packages whose message types you use in
##   your messages/services/actions (e.g. std_msgs, actionlib_msgs, ...).
## * In the file package.xml:
##   * add a build_depend tag for "message_generation"
##   * add a build_depend and a run_depend tag for each package in MSG_DEP_SET
##   * If MSG_DEP_SET isn't empty the following dependency has been pulled in
##     but can be declared for certainty nonetheless:
##     * add a run_depend tag for "message_runtime"
## * In this file (CMakeLists.txt):
##   * add "message_generation" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
##   * add "message_runtime" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
##     catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS ...)
##   * uncomment the add_*_files sections below as needed
##     and list every .msg/.srv/.action file to be processed
##   * uncomment the generate_messages entry below
##   * add every package in MSG_DEP_SET to generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ...)

## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
# add_message_files(
#   FILES
#   Message1.msg
#   Message2.msg
# )

## Generate services in the 'srv' folder
# add_service_files(
#   FILES
#   Service1.srv
#   Service2.srv
# )

## Generate actions in the 'action' folder
# add_action_files(
#   FILES
#   Action1.action
#   Action2.action
# )

## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
# generate_messages(
#   DEPENDENCIES
#   std_msgs  # Or other packages containing msgs
# )

################################################
## Declare ROS dynamic reconfigure parameters ##
################################################

## To declare and build dynamic reconfigure parameters within this
## package, follow these steps:
## * In the file package.xml:
##   * add a build_depend and a run_depend tag for "dynamic_reconfigure"
## * In this file (CMakeLists.txt):
##   * add "dynamic_reconfigure" to
##     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
##   * uncomment the "generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options" section below
##     and list every .cfg file to be processed

## Generate dynamic reconfigure parameters in the 'cfg' folder
# generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(
#   cfg/DynReconf1.cfg
#   cfg/DynReconf2.cfg
# )

###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################
## The catkin_package macro generates cmake config files for your package
## Declare things to be passed to dependent projects
## INCLUDE_DIRS: uncomment this if you package contains header files
## LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need
## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES octo_to_pcl
#  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp tf
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
include_directories(
# include
 ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
 ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
 ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS}

)

## Declare a C++ library
# add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
#   src/${PROJECT_NAME}/octo_to_pcl.cpp
# )

## Add cmake target dependencies of the library
## as an example, code may need to be generated before libraries
## either from message generation or dynamic reconfigure
# add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

## Declare a C++ executable
## With catkin_make all packages are built within a single CMake context
## The recommended prefix ensures that target names across packages don't collide
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_node src/octo_to_pcl_node.cpp)

## Rename C++ executable without prefix
## The above recommended prefix causes long target names, the following renames the
## target back to the shorter version for ease of user use
## e.g. "rosrun someones_pkg node" instead of "rosrun someones_pkg someones_pkg_node"
# set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}_node PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME node PREFIX "")

## Add cmake target dependencies of the executable
## same as for the library above
# add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}_node ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
 target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_node
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
   ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES} 
   ${PCL_LIBRARIES}
   ${OCTOMAP_LIBRARIES}
 )

#############
## Install ##
#############

# all install targets should use catkin DESTINATION variables
# See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/adv_user_guide/variables.html

## Mark executable scripts (Python etc.) for installation
## in contrast to setup.py, you can choose the destination
# install(PROGRAMS
#   scripts/my_python_script
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark executables and/or libraries for installation
# install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_NAME}_node
#   ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark cpp header files for installation
# install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
#   FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
#   PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
# )

## Mark other files for installation (e.g. launch and bag files, etc.)
# install(FILES
#   # myfile1
#   # myfile2
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
# )

#############
## Testing ##
#############

## Add gtest based cpp test target and link libraries
# catkin_add_gtest(${PROJECT_NAME}-test test/test_octo_to_pcl.cpp)
# if(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}-test)
#   target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}-test ${PROJECT_NAME})
# endif()

## Add folders to be run by python nosetests
# catkin_add_nosetests(test)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/293599/bloom-generate-is-not-generating-generating-executable-files/) by [billyDong](https://answers.ros.org/users/29477/billydong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2018-06-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

(I've included your `CMakeLists.txt` in your question text)

You don't have any `install(..)` statements in your `CMakeLists.txt`.

As a `.deb` will only include artefacts that have actually been installed, it's completely logical that your `.deb` installed package does not have your nodes - they're just not included in the `.deb`.

You'll need to add `install(..)` statements.

Please refer to [Building and installing C++ executables](http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/building_executables.html) and perhaps [Building and installing C++ libraries and headers](http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/index.html) in the Catkin documentation.

> It works fine when I use catkin.

yes, and that is because you probably don't use `catkin_make install`, but instead rely on the *devel space*.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-11**:
Note that this is not a ROS problem, but a generic CMake one (`install(..)` is a CMake command, not a Catkin one).

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-06-11**:
Once you add `install()` statements to your CMakeLists.txt, you can test that they work by doing `catkin_make install`, then source the `install/setup.bash` and test that your nodes and launch files still run correctly.

**Comment by [billyDong](https://answers.ros.org/users/29477/billydong/) on 2018-08-21**:
Thank you, I needed to uncomment the install options on the cMakeLists